# Test IE7 without installing it - how?

Tags: debugging, testing, internet-explorer-7

Is there a way to test IE7 functionality (intented to test the functionality of a website) without installing IE7?

Something like an online service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These options are only useful if you're able to install programs (but don't want to install IE7).

One way would be to use [IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage). It's not 100% but it is generally good (I've had some issues where it didn't display the same as the browser it was showing - mostly IE6).

Another (better) option would be to install [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx) and use the [Virtual PC Images](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) that are available for IE browser compatibility.

Comment: IETester seems to be a great thing at first sight - it is fast and easy to use - even FirebugLite works!!!! Thx!

Answer (score 2):

http://browsershots.org/

**EDIT** That'll give you screenshots, as the URL implies, but you can't test functionality. You'll need to install IE7 for that, unless you can find/convince someone to give you VNC or RDP access.

Most web developers keep around VMs with the different IEs for this.

Comment: well, this will give me the possibility to test static sites, i need something to test dynamical things

Comment: Caught that about 10 seconds after I posted, and you posted about 3 seconds before that!

Comment: :)  a VM seems to be no option cause we would need another windows licence

Comment: Check Jonathon's answer. Microsoft knows this and provides images for free, for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

I do this kind of testing on a daily basis and I really do recommend you to install a few virtual machines with the different web browsers to really be 100% sure how its rendered.

I'm using the free Virtual Box (http://www.virtualbox.org/). You got Microsofts Virtual PC but have not used that for a while.

You are supposed to be able to install a "copy" of your own windows OS with same serial key without breaking rules as long it runs on your machine.

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

there are a number of sites purportedly offering such services, like browsershots( .org), but they mostly give you static screenshots.

The best option for a real solid test though is to install any number of IE versions by using virtual machines, each with it's own version of IE on it.